# Electronics Manufacturing Engineers: What needs to meet IPC-6012 the finished copper or the starting copper foil?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, manufacturing, manufacturing-process

I have a PCB that has a finished copper thickness of 1 oz on all layers and must meet IPC-6012 requirements for Class 2.

Does this mean that the manufacturer can start with 0.5 oz copper foil then plate 0.5 oz of copper and the finished copper thickness needs to meet IPC-6012 or have a minimum thickness of finished  thickness 47.9 μm [1,886 μin].

Or Does this mean that the manufacturer must start with a foil material that meets IPC-6012 for 0.5 oz, 33.4μm [1,315μin] and then plate 0.5 oz of copper and the finished copper does not need to meet IPC-6012

Comment: Do you have a copy of the document?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in the answer to the question above:
The second is correct. If you specify 1 oz finished copper, the manufacturer will start with 0.5 oz copper foil which meets  IPC-6012 for 0.5 oz, final process thickness minimum of 33.4μm [1,315μin]. And then plate up to about 1 oz. However, the manufacturer will meet the minimum copper thickness for 0.5 oz copper, not 1 oz copper. If your design requires meeting 1 oz copper on external layers ,or 47.9 μm [1,886 μin] minimum copper thickness, then you must specify 2 oz copper so that the manufacturer start with 1 oz copper meeting IPC 6012 minimum thickness after processing of or a minimum thickness of 47.9 μm [1,886 μin].